# How to change the logo image dynamically when user change language?

Tags: 6, theming, i18n-l10n

How to change the logo image dinamycally when user change language by clicking in the flag?
Exist an easy way to resolve this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in page.tpl.php some condition like

```
if ($user-> language == 'ru') $logo_url = '../rus.jpg'
```

etc

Comment: This should really go in a preprocess method in template.php